# Event on HTML element does not get triggered if other one is being executed. How to queue events?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have the following problem:

I got 2 events on a div which basically swaps content of a child element on a mouse-enter and swaps it again on a mouse-leave. It looks like this:

```
<div class="product-tile__wrapper" onmouseenter="slideButtonsPrice(this)" onmouseleave="slideButtonsPrice(this)">.
```

The problem is that, if the function triggered first is not finished - any other event is not fired up.

So it turns out that, when mouseleave is done fast enough while the first swap being still executed - it fails to trigger.

Here is the codepen exactly showing the described problem: https://codepen.io/jdziurdzikowski/pen/dKeZYO

How can I make successive events like that happen the right way?

Comment: https://www.google.nl/search?q=stop+animation+jquery

Comment: Thank you, it helped to solve the problem !

Comment: When asking questions, please include all relevant code in the question itself, here on Stack Overflow, not only on CodePen. You can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so, and to have it run, here on SO.